# How to fix if statement always returnig false when using regex

Tags: regex, bash

After dowloading a torrent I want to move it based on if its a movie or series. If it's a series the name contains S or s following by 2 numbers. for ex S01.

I tried a simple if command with regex but my code always get a false result.

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ([s|S][0-9][0-9]\w*)\b ]]; then
    mv to series folder command
else
    mv to movies folder command
fi
```

It doesnt matter what I input to the $1 parameter the if result will be false always.

Comment: I don't think bash uses PCRE.

Comment: Specifically, bash's regex syntax doesn't recognize `\w` or `\b` as shortcuts; it just treats them as funny ways to write the letters "w" and "b".

Answer (score 1):

Your match expression is incorrect - to match s or S, just use [sS]

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ([sS][0-9][0-9]*) ]]; then
    echo "series"
else
    echo "movie"
fi
```

Output:

```
$ bash del.sh s01
series
$ bash del.sh fff
movie
$ bash del.sh S02
series
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost what I intended. But your script matches with only 1 number too for ex:"s1". Can you modify it to only match with 2 numbers?